# Why there is Qt::UserRole in delegate in this example?

Tags: c++, qt, roles

I read a tutorial book about delegates in QT. There is a simple example. We create QComboBox as editor with 3 values: "", "Pan", "Pani". We reimplement 3 methods: `createEditor`, `setEditorData`, `setModelData` in TitleDelegate class. I understand the first and the second one.

```
QWidget * TitleDelegate :: createEditor (QWidget *parent ,const QStyleOptionViewItem &,const QModelIndex &) const 
{
   QComboBox *widget=new QComboBox (parent);
   QStringList itemList; itemList <<""<<"Pan"<<"Pani";
   widget ->addItems(itemList);
   return widget;
}
```

```
void TitleDelegate :: setEditorData (QWidget *editor , const QModelIndex &index) const 
{
   QComboBox *widget=static_cast < QComboBox *>( editor);
   int value=index.model () ->data(index ,Qt::EditRole).toInt ();
   widget -> setCurrentIndex (value);
}
```

```
void TitleDelegate :: setModelData (QWidget *editor , QAbstractItemModel *model , const QModelIndex &index) const 
{
   QComboBox *widget = static_cast < QComboBox *>( editor);
   int value = widget -> currentIndex ();
   model ->setData(index , widget -> currentText (), Qt::DisplayRole );
   model ->setData(index , value , Qt::UserRole);
}
```

But I don't understand line from `setModelData`:

`model ->setData(index , value , Qt::UserRole);`

In the book there is explanation: We have to save `value` to can use it in `setEditorData` method to know active list's element.

Why we use `Qt::UserRole`? I think we should use `Qt::EditRole`.

Comment: We do not know, that code seems to have problems since as you point out, you should use only one role: or Qt::UserRole or Qt::EditRole. You should write an email to the author or use another book

Comment: @eyllanesc Thank you for answer. And I have another question: Can I change in this code ( in setEditorData ) Qt::EditRole to Qt::UserRole? I think I have to use Qt::EditRole, because this role is created to that mission. In this code I don't say: Qt::UserRole is to set proper data in ```setEditorData```. But maybe I have to remember: when I use in my code Qt::UserRole it is data to set it in ```setEditorData```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this [Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum) about `Qt::ItemDataRole`:
[image]

But For **User roles**:
[image]

As It says :

> For user roles, it is up to the developer to decide which types to use
> and ensure that components use the correct types when accessing and
> setting data.